# Laser divergence/convergence over large distance

Tags: space, laser

I have hit a roadblock in my simulation, where there are 2 authors with contradicting equations on the model.

So I have simulated both, and drew it out for a few diameters. My dish size is 40m.

I am unsure which model to use for laser transmission over 40,000km from space to Earth. The more intuitive/logical model is the 2nd author's.

But is the first one correct? I know Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle is at play in causing the divergence on the non-parallel line photon paths from electron source emissions. But does light really take on this inverse pattern?

To me it also seems similar to the double slit experiment in QM, whereby decreasing the slit diameter decreases the diameter of the interference pattern, but it eventually reaches a point where the diameter of the interference pattern suddenly increases, and this is a phenomena to this date, from my knowledge. Could something similar be the case here? And any recommendations on which equation to use?

[image]

Where `d_t` = diameter of transmitter dish, and `d_r` = diameter of receiver dish

Edit: to make the question clear, "Does light emission truly behave like case 1, whereby the angle inverses proportionally at a certain point relative to increasing dish diameter, the same as the double slit experiment phenomena? Apparently yes, it does."

Comment: As for 2.44 multiplier it's probably from Rayleigh criterion. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution
Unfortunately I can't help with the rest.

Comment: (1) You haven't really fully described the situation - wavelengths, dish shapes, etc. (2) To help with that, you should link the original articles. (3) It seems from the images that the articles are discussing different cases - it may be that the only thing "wrong" is assuming they should agree. (4) NASA? Infallible?? Ummm... you should probably reevaluate your method of evaluating the correctness of papers.

Comment: Wavelength is in the image, dish shape is circular of course, the 2.44 multiplier of an airy disc is used by NASA. No the article aren't discussing different things, they both use different equations to determine the receiver size. The question is simple, and doesn't even need to relate to the articles; "does light emission truly behave like case 1, whereby the angle inverses proportionally at a certain point relative to increasing dish diameter".